# Transaction commit / rollback execution problem

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures, transactions, rollback

I am working on stored procedures in MySQL and I am not getting a hang of the transaction and handler part, at this point I am just confused why do we use transactions and handlers, and the reason for that is one place it works and one place it dosen't

This is the syntax I have been Using

```
BEGIN

DECLARE exit handler for sqlexception
begin 
    rollback;
    resignal;
end;

START TRANSACTION;

INSERT INTO ch.new_table(new_table_col1,new_table_col2,new_table_col3)
VALUES(nt1,nt2,nt3);

INSERT INTO ch.new_table2(new_table_col1,new_table_col2,new_table_col3)
VALUES(t1,t2,t3);

COMMIT;

END
```

Now I have been using the syntax that i pasted above as a stored procedure to insert values into new_table and new_table2

Once I have executed it records gets added into new_table and new_table2 which both have autoincrementing ID, and as I add 1 gets added to the PK,just like an AI ID should

but when i apply the same to my main script if there is an error in insertion then it skips that id, for example if i entered wrong data type for ID 7 it dosent it thorws and error and dosent insert that when i correct it and then insert again it inserts an id for 8

so I naturally checked why was the synatx script working fine, it works fine without the rollback handler and also the transaction and commit removed from it

and the same thing is opposite for my main table it does not work even if i include the rollback handler or the transaction commit block

```
PROCEDURE `IU_SCD`(_Order_ID int, _Customer_id int, _Receipt_no int,_Date_of_pay date, _Cheque_no int, _Amount int, _SC_Bank varchar(65),_Mode_of_pay varchar(45) )

BEGIN

DECLARE exit handler for sqlexception
begin 
    rollback;
    resignal;
end;

START TRANSACTION;
        IF _Order_ID = 0 THEN 
        INSERT INTO ch03.Order_details( Customer_id, Receipt_no, Date_of_pay, Cheque_no, Amount, SC_Bank)
        VALUE (_Customer_id, _Receipt_no, _Date_of_pay, _Cheque_no, _Amount, _SC_Bank);
                    
                    SELECT last_insert_id() INTO @SCDLID;
                    
#____insert or update in Mode_of_pay table____________________________________________________________________
  BEGIN 
    
                SELECT MOP_id FROM ch03.mop 
                WHERE Mode_of_pay = _Mode_of_pay 
                INTO @SCD_MOP_id;
        
            BEGIN
                IF (@SCD_MOP_id IS NULL) THEN 
                
                        INSERT INTO ch03.mop (Mode_of_pay)
                        VALUES (_Mode_of_pay);
                        
                    SELECT last_insert_id() INTO @SCD_MOP_id ;
                    
                    UPDATE ch03.Order_details SET SCD_MOP_id = @SCD_MOP_id
                    WHERE Order_ID = @SCDLID;

                    
                ELSE UPDATE ch03.Order_details
                
                    SET 
                        SCD_MOP_id = @SCD_MOP_id
                    WHERE Order_ID = @SCDLID;

                END IF;
            END;
    
    END;
#___________________________________________________________________________________________________________

        
        ELSE UPDATE ch03.Order_details
        SET Receipt_no = _Receipt_no,  
            Date_of_pay = _Date_of_pay, 
            Cheque_no = _Cheque_no,
            Amount = _Amount,
            SC_Bank = _SC_Bank;     
            

        
        
#____insert or update in Mode_of_pay table____________________________________________________________________
  BEGIN 
    
                SELECT MOP_id FROM ch03.mop 
                WHERE Mode_of_pay = _Mode_of_pay 
                INTO @SCD_MOP_id;
        
            BEGIN
                IF (@SCD_MOP_id IS NULL) THEN 
                
                        INSERT INTO ch03.mop (Mode_of_pay)
                        VALUES (_Mode_of_pay);
                        
                    SELECT last_insert_id() INTO @SCD_MOP_id ;
                    
                    UPDATE ch03.Order_details SET SCD_MOP_id = @SCD_MOP_id
                    WHERE Order_ID = _Order_ID;

                    
                ELSE UPDATE ch03.Order_details
                
                    SET 
                        SCD_MOP_id = @SCD_MOP_id
                    WHERE Order_ID = _Order_ID;

                END IF;
            END;
    
    END;
#___________________________________________________________________________________________________________
        
        
   END IF;
   
   
  COMMIT;

END
```

Comment: *but when i apply the same to my main script if there is an error in insertion then it skips that id, for example if i entered wrong data type for ID 7 it dosent it thorws and error and dosent insert that when i correct it and then insert again it inserts an id for 8* This is correct, the gap **must** occur in such situation. If you need a column with continuous numeration then you must create additional column which is assigned programmatically (for example, using trigger), autoincremented primary key is not applicable for such purposes.

Comment: @Akina Thats all right and all, I don't mind that, what i mind is why does it behave diffrently for the similar script, in the first script it does'nt skip numbers